# How to test WiFi direct connectivity programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, wifi-direct

I have developed Windows app to connect with Android phone using Windows WiFi Direct API. Now though seems device is connected via WiFi direct I cannot send/receive files sometimes over UPnP protocol. Now I want to know if programmatically I can check the WiFi direct connection is stable or not. I want to be sure if the problem is in connection side of in other features side effect. How to check if the connection is flawless or not..

Comment: _[Shows how to use the Wi-Fi Direct API to discover devices and connect to the them over Wi-Fi Direct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/wifidirect/)_ and [`WiFiDirectDevice` Class (UWP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifidirect.wifidirectdevice?view=winrt-19041)

Comment: @MickyD lets say, after following those steps device is connected but at any point of time I want to test if connected or the existing connection is lost. Any API to test programmatically?

Comment: Could you please use [WiFiDirectConnectionStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifidirect.wifidirectconnectionstatus?view=winrt-19041) to judge the connection status?